# Crypto Pro Browser Plugin: получить имя провайдера

Tags: javascript, криптопро

Через плагин Crypto Pro ([проверка работы  плагина Crypto Pro](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/cades/demopage/simple.html)) получаю список всех имеющихся сертификатов на компьютере (вместе отображаются и те, что находятся в реестре и те, что хранятся на USB-носителе). Мне нужно из них выбрать только те, которые находятся на USB-носителе. На [на форуме Crypto Pro](https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=9408) мне подсказали, что это можно сделать через объект сертификата PrivateKey. Через данный объект можно получить значение ContainerName, однако при попытке это сделать, получаю ошибку **"Не поддерживается (0x80004001)"**. Способ, при помощи которого я пытаюсь его извлечь, вроде бы верный, так как из этого же объекта я могу получить значение ProviderName.  Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Как можно получить имя контейнера, в котором находится сертификат, используя Crypto Pro Browser Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения за беспокойство,  заработало). Я скачала файл **async_code.js** с [сайта проверки плагина Crypto Pro](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/cades/demopage/simple.html) и запросила нужные данные в функции **FillCertList_Async()**.

```
try { cert = yield certs.Item(i);
                console.log('yield cert.PrivateKey=');
                let param = yield cert.PrivateKey;
                try{
                  console.log(yield param.ProviderName);
                  console.log(yield param.ProviderType);
                  console.log(yield param.KeySpec);
                  console.log(yield param.UniqueContainerName);
                  console.log(yield param.ContainerName);
                }catch(e){
                  console.log('ERROR!  ' + e.message);
                }
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert("Ошибка при перечислении сертификатов: " + cadesplugin.getLastError(ex));
                return;
            }
```